# Reading Data from Cloud Storage without downloading the file using a Google Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

My application consists of a `Google Cloud Function` that is `HTTP` triggered. On triggering. it should calculate the number of lines of data stored in the files in `Cloud Storage`. I used the `blob.download_as_string()` but because of the number of files the time taken to download the files is too long. I am using `Python 3.7`. Can someone suggest an alternative?

Comment: If your question is actually about Cloud Functions as you've tagged, would you like to edit the question say more about how that's being used here?

Comment: I am using a `Google Cloud Function` with `HTTP trigger` . On triggering it should calculate the number of lines of data stored in the files in `Cloud Storage`.

Comment: I tried this manner,                                                                       `###file_path is the folder path in the bucket                                                              file_read_path = os.path.join(file_path +'/'+ fileName)                      count = len(open(file_read_path).readlines(  ))`  Looks like this is a wrong approach

Comment: It would be a good idea to edit the question to add information rather than commenting.  Code is hard to read in comments.

Comment: Please edit the questions as @DougStevenson suggested. From my side I would like to add question how do you use this line count? Seems to be not very effective to download whole file only to get number of lines....

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I loaded the entire data from the `Cloud Storage` files using the `blob.download_as_string()` and converted into a `numpy` array. Each line will have only one element of the array, this way I found the number of lines. yes, its not very effective..I am still trying for an alternative method where the files can be opened directly and read without downloading them.

Comment: I think metadata of the files can be used. size gives the number of bytes stored in the file. I know that 2bytes make 1 element. This way I used to calculate the number of lines. I was able to reduce the time by a small factor which is again not sufficient enough.